# Getting linker error while trying to compile Paho samples

Tags: c++, c, mqtt, paho

I want to compile the samples of paho.mqtt.cpp but I cannot seem to compile them. When i run
`cmake paho.mqtt.cpp/src/samples` it gives me the error u see in the title and here under:

````
```/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `main':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::async_client(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mqtt::iclient_persistence*)'
/usr/bin/ld: ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::connect_options(mqtt::connect_options const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::connect(mqtt::connect_options)'
/usr/bin/ld: ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x40c): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::publish(std::shared_ptr<mqtt::message const>)'
/usr/bin/ld: ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x554): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::~async_client()'
/usr/bin/ld: ws_publish.cpp:(.text+0x768): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::~async_client()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::exception::error_str[abi:cxx11](int)':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt9exception9error_strB5cxx11Ei[_ZN4mqtt9exception9error_strB5cxx11Ei]+0x18): undefined reference to `MQTTAsync_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::exception::reason_code_str[abi:cxx11](int)':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt9exception15reason_code_strB5cxx11Ei[_ZN4mqtt9exception15reason_code_strB5cxx11Ei]+0x28): undefined reference to `MQTTReasonCode_toString'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::properties::~properties()':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt10propertiesD2Ev[_ZN4mqtt10propertiesD5Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to `MQTTProperties_free'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::connect_options_builder::connect_options_builder()':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builderC2Ev[_ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builderC5Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::connect_options()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::connect_options_builder::http_proxy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builder10http_proxyERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builder10http_proxyERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::set_http_proxy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::connect_options_builder::finalize()':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builder8finalizeEv[_ZN4mqtt23connect_options_builder8finalizeEv]+0x20): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::connect_options(mqtt::connect_options const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `mqtt::async_client::disconnect()':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt12async_client10disconnectEv[_ZN4mqtt12async_client10disconnectEv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `mqtt::disconnect_options::disconnect_options()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/ws_publish.o: in function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<mqtt::message>::construct<mqtt::message, mqtt::buffer_ref<char>, mqtt::buffer_ref<char>, int&, bool&, mqtt::properties const&>(mqtt::message*, mqtt::buffer_ref<char>&&, mqtt::buffer_ref<char>&&, int&, bool&, mqtt::properties const&)':
ws_publish.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4mqtt7messageEE9constructIS2_JNS1_10buffer_refIcEES6_RiRbRKNS1_10propertiesEEEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4mqtt7messageEE9constructIS2_JNS1_10buffer_refIcEES6_RiRbRKNS1_10propertiesEEEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0xb4): undefined reference to `mqtt::message::message(mqtt::buffer_ref<char>, mqtt::buffer_ref<char>, int, bool, mqtt::properties const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/build.make:84: ws_publish] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:106: CMakeFiles/ws_publish.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2 ```
````

I know it is a problem of the library not linking but cant seem to find a fix.

Comment: You're not supposed to invoke CMake like this.  Run it on the "paho.mqtt.cpp" directory instead and run `make`.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on [how to build form source](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp#building-from-source) in the readme file of the repository, line by line and you most likely won't be having this problem.